# how to set c++ if...else statement for user input?

Tags: c++, debugging, c++builder, vcl, rad-studio

i would like the TEdit label to print "Success!" for correct username input and "Error" for incorrect username input. i have tried this code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::UsernameEditChange(TObject *Sender)
{
    string username = "admin";
    string result = (username == "admin") ? "Success!" : "Error";
    std::cout << result;
}
```

i get an error saying the type "string" is unknown. how do i fix this so that the if...else statement functions for user input?

Comment: If `string` is supposed to be `std::string` then write it as such or add `using std::string;` to your code. Have you included `<string>`?

Comment: @Chris `using std::string;` like `using namespace std;` is the wrong kind of lazy (with reduced impact), but nameclashes in big projects can still occur.  Just type `std::string` explicitly everywhere. Namespace std has a short name for a reason ;)

Comment: I would also **strongly** advise against using `using` in your code. Simply make sure to `#include <string>` and write out the class scope `std::string`.

Comment: That's not an "if ... else statement", it's a conditional expression. (And it's completely irrelevant to your issue.)

Comment: Why are you using `std::cout` in a GUI app? You should put your result into your UI instead, eg `Edit1->Text = result.c_str();` or use a popup message such as from `ShowMessage()` or `Application->MessageBox()`